# How to check return value of Find statment in shell script?

Tags: awk, shell

How can I check the return value of "Find" statement in shell script 
I am use Find in my script , if find statement don't find any file the execute exit  !! 
I want to check the return value of "Find" if it found any files or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redirect output of the `find` command to a file called say `output.txt` then you can check if the size of that file is 0 or not by using `-s` option;

```
if [[ -s "output.txt" ]]
then
echo "File is not empty!"
else
echo "File is empty!"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count the number of files found by `find` using the `wc -l` command:

```
 export result=`find . -name *.txt | wc -l`
```

You can now check `result` to see how many files where found

```
 if [ $result == "0" ]; then echo zero found; fi
```